# How can I hide my database information in Java?

Tags: java, database, security

I'm trying to figure out database security in Java. Like video games, desktop app and others that uses database in its code and how they can store their password in it.

Here's an example:
There's an application that uses MySQL database for storing users data and their information.
A user is registered and logged into our app. He has 0 coin in start. He bought 100 coin from shop and his *coin* data changed to 100. During the steps that I mention, he always use database for insert and update his data.

In a nutshell, how can I hide my database information (username and maybe IP?) in my Java code?

In addition, I've searched a while and found that you can send web request for information, but if anyone finds the code of request, they also can make their program and use same request as my app. So, I cannot figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, the database is in a server that you controls, and you provide an API to make requests.

In these requests there's no information about database username or password, that should be on your server.

Then, you need to protect that connection. Normally, yo do that with authentication and authorization. You need to provide username and passwords to your users, and that is present in any request they do to your server. Also, you need to make controls in your server to control what can do each user (control that a user cannot perform any query they want).

A common way to do this is using federated authentication and authorization, with protocols like OAuth2.0 or OpenID.

Also, you need to make sure that you use HTTPS, or attackers could capture the traffic and extract all the request information.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you never talk from the Front End (UI, mobile application, whatever) to the Database.

Usually Frontend talks to some backend server - an entry point to the backend word, a gateway (there is indeed such a term). From that point, the request can be routed to another server, or be processed in the same server (depending on the application, its complexity, architecture, etc) and only after that the information should be stored in the database (or queried from the database and returned back to the end user).

Only the gateway is exposed to the "outer word", all the backend services and of course the database should be protected from the accidental/malicious access at different levels:

- at the level of network so that it will be physically impossible to connect to it if you're not making a connection from one of the backed servers
- at the level of application security - so that it will be impossible to connect to the database without appropriate credentials (username, password, etc). Note this are not the same Username/password that the end user must know in order to login to the application, these are the data about the user, it has nothing to do with the user / password required to connect to the database.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your specific question is to use Java's "secret storage" features. [This question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/111346/best-reasonable-way-to-store-a-secret-safely) may be a starting point.

The wider point is - please do not make a MySQL database directly accessible from the internet if that's what you're thinking. The security of such a solution would require specialist skills and your question suggests you don't have those skills...

If your application runs outside a local area network (and even if it runs inside the network), you probably want to put a central service layer in place - and API - to handle requests from your client applications. In this case, you still need authentication - you don't want to allow unauthenticated users to add, remove or spend your coins. Most API frameworks have out-of-the-box solutions for this.